# why laravel 4 operator show weird output in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know that `{{ }}` is laravel 4 operator but what if i use this in laravel 5.

I am trying it in laravel5 , it works but show some weird output

so should i use this operator or not in laravel 5???

Comment: Are you talking about Blade output?

Comment: Refer http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade and if the issue still exists share the code and present a desired output image or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blade syntax in Laravel 4.x was as follows

- `{{ $variable }}` to output a variable without escaping the contents.
- `{{{ $variable }}}` to output a variable whilst escaping the contents.

In Laravel 5.x this was changed to

- `{!! $variable !!}` to output a variable without escaping the contents.
- `{{ $variable }}` to output a variable whilst escaping the contents.

The reason you're seeing "weird" output is because the content which previously wasn't being escaped now is. What you're seeing is HTML entities and such being converted.

In order to get the expected output you'll need to change your blade templates to use `{!! $variable !!}` where appropriate.

If you don't want to go through all of the blade templates to make the change you can do the following

Add the following lines at the bottom of `AppServiceProvider@register`:

```
\Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
\Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
\Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
```

> This should not be done lightly, and may make your application more vulnerable to XSS exploits. Also, comments with {{-- will no longer work.

These changes are documented in the [Upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) under the heading Blade Tag Changes.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are from blade, a template engine included in laravel 4 and 5.

It helps you to write easy code by converting a `<your name>.blade.php` into a full php file.

```
Hello, {{ $name }}.
```

will be converted to

```
Hello, <?php echo $name ?>
```

Remember the brackets will use htmlspecialchars so when you want to print a html element you need

```
{!! $myElement !!}
```